# How do i add lines/strings to richTextBox1?

Tags: c#, winforms

`ListsExtractions.text1` contain 49 items
But in the end `richTextbox1` is empty.
How can i add the strings/lines from `ListsExtractions.text1` to the `richTextBox1` ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{
    public partial class DisplayLockedThreads : Form
    {
        public DisplayLockedThreads()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < ListsExtractions.text1.Count; i++)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = ListsExtractions.text1[i];
            }
        }

        private void DisplayLockedThreads_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

`ListsExtractions.text1` contain 49 items
But in the end `richTextbox1` is empty.

Comment: Have you tried using richTextBox1.AppendText ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListsExtractions.text1.Count; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = ListsExtractions.text1[i];
        }
```

to this

```
richTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, ListsExtractions.text1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling it twice , move from constructor to the load event your code:

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace ScrollLabelTest
    {
        public partial class DisplayLockedThreads : Form
        {
            public DisplayLockedThreads()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }

            private void DisplayLockedThreads_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               richTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, ListsExtractions.text1 );    
            }
        }
    }
```